Do any languages have inflection tables with 7 or more attributes?
Here is some examples I collected, where the number indicates how many attributes are in the inflection table headers:
1. past participle = astiqué + /as.ti.ke/
2. present participle, simple/compound = astiquer
2. nominative, singular = æfwela
3. past participle, singular, masculine = abrogado
3. present, perfect, infinitive = abrāsisse
4. singular, 1st/2nd/3rd, indicative, present = astique + /as.tik/
4. singular, 1st/2nd/3rd, indicative, conditional perfect = aurais astiqué + /ɔ.ʁɛ as.ti.ke/
5. active, singular, 1st/2nd/3rd, past (perfect) indicative, male = أَجْرَيْتُ + ʔajraytu
5. passive, singular, 2nd, non-past (imperfect) indicative, female = تُجْرِينَ + tujrīna
5. active, subjunctive, plural, pluperfect, 1st = abrāserīmus
6. passive, singular, 2nd, non-past (imperfect), indicative, feminine = tujrīna + تُجْرِينَ

The last #6 one I got from ChatGPT, so not sure it's correct, but the others I copied from these links on Wiktionary:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/astiquer#French
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrogar#Spanish
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%89#Arabic
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A6fwela#Old_English
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D#Sanskrit

Do we have any cases where there are more than 6 attributes being used? Maybe, even, some of these attributes are really "compound attributes" which I'm not fully aware of, so if we break them down, they become more properties?
If there are cases with more properties, can you provide one for each number like 7, 8, 9, to 10? If there are more than 10 I don't know what I'm going to do for mobile layout :) (this is from v0.dev chatting, nowhere close to nice enough yet for all the number of attributes I'm trying to layout).


Thank you for the downvotes with explanation.

Various Bantu languages do, with their verb extensions. For example, a Lingála verb can mark:

Subject noun class/person
Subject number
Object noun class/person
Object number
TAM (tense/aspect/mood)
Applicative or not
Causative or not
Reciprocal or not
Reversive or not
Passive or not

For a total of 10. The key is those last five (the "verb extensions"), each of which can either be present or absent, for a total of 32 combinations (some of which are nonsensical).
However, most references won't actually consider these to be ten separate categories of inflection. The first two pairs are usually unified into "subject person/class/number" and "object person/class/number", for example, and the verb extensions could be considered a type of derivation rather than inflection (it's always exactly the same for every verb).

Frame challenge: some languages have an unbounded number.
In Georgian, for example, you can stack causatives to make arbitrarily long verbs: "I made him make her make them make you do this". Nobody would actually do this in everyday usage, but there's no theoretical maximum.
This doesn't mean your tool is useless, just that it's not useful for languages like this with a high degree of polysynthesis. (Inuktitut is another famous one.) For these languages, rather than listing every combination, it would probably be better to split it into components and display the meaning of each one in a chain.

Where can I learn more about your last sentence design-wise?

Yeah, I am only following the major trends in data organization for each language, so for the languages that have tables, I will make these combinations. But for the polysynthetic or agglutinative languages like you mention (Inuktitut), I haven't gotten there yet. The main "sacred languages" (Chinese, Hebrew, Arabic, Tamil, Greek, Latin, Punjabi, English) are not agglutinative, and my focus is on these sacred languages first (ones with rich ancient textual resources).

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156163/word-ui

Same in Japanese, where you can (theoretically) stack things like negatives: 働きたくなくなくない hataraki-taku-naku-naku-nai ‘(I) do not not not want to work’.

And I agree that it’s unclear how you could even fit Inuit languages with their extreme suffix chaining into this sort of ‘inflection table’. How do you even measure how many attributes there are in Greenlandic nalunaara­suartaatili­oqateeralior­finnialikker­saatiginialikker­saatilillara­nata­goorunar­suarooq ‘once again they tried to build a giant radio station, but it was apparently only on the drawing board’? (That is not a compound, but a single root with a bajillion suffixes.)

@LancePollard Actually, scratch that, I can think of one source on displaying these "chains". See here (read the section on "morphophonology") and here.

I am not trying to fit every language into inflection tables, FWIW, just the ones that traditionally have inflection tables...

Old Irish would require many more attributes to fully capture the inflection of the verb.
See this diagram of the Old Irish verbal complex from David Stifter: [Link]

Including the pronominal slots (which mark pronominal objects, or can be used to mark focus on pronominal arguments), it has 10 different inflectional slots (note that the suffix slot is derivational).
In terms of the attributes which are marked by these slots it has:

Aspect: marked on the ending and/or stem
"Dependency" (a verb is dependent if it is relative or has certain other particles in the verbal complex, including the negative polarity particle): marked on the ending and with stem changes
Focus salience: marked by whether the focus is marked with a nota augens or deictic clitic
Focus person: marked by the nota augens or deictic
Focus number: marked by the nota augens or deictic
Interrogativity: marked by an interrogative particle (note that this is independently of mood)
Mood: marked by the ending
Object person: marked by either an infixed or suffixed pronominal (which is used depends on the form of the verb)
Object number: marked by either an infixed or suffixed pronominal (which is used depends on the form of the verb)
"Perspectivity" (marking a verb either as perfect, or as describing the possibility of an action): marked by the augment (note that this is independently of aspect)
Relativity: marked with the relative particle
Polarity: marked with the negative particle  (note that this is independently of mood)
Subject person: marked with the ending
Subject number: marked with the ending
Tense: marked on the ending and/or stem
Voice: marked on the ending and/or stem

That makes up at least 16 different attributes (and verbs with both a nota augens and deictic would have more). This also isn't getting into the fact that (many) conjunctions are actually part of the verbal complex itself rather than independent, and so could reasonably be included.
For reasons of practicality, Old Irish verb tables are always for only a narrow subset of possible forms (e.g. the aspect, mood, subject person, subject number, tense, and voice seen in Latin, but also usually dependency/polarity and perspectivity) but, in principle, a complete table should include them all.
